# JSON data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

in our database environment, I observed that few tables which are using JSON data type, having performance issue even they aren't storing more than 8k rows. Howsoever, this situation improves when we do a full vacuum and works okay but this should be a permanent solution. Although, having a GIN index isn't helping much, any idea why this could be?

Comment: A "table" can't have a performance issue. Only a query can. If you want to get a more detailed answer you will need to provide the query you are having problems with and the the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for that query generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`**

Comment: More often than not, if  a `vacuum full` solves performance issues, this indicates either a poorly written application that doesn't end transactions properly or a wrong autovacuum configuration. Also: what is your exact Postgres version?

Comment: My PostgreSQL is version 11.